# How to install eclipse plugin in Lotus Notes client silently/Programatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes, silent

I need to install an eclipse-based plugin in Lotus Notes Client 8.5. The requirement is that this should not have any user involvement. I want to know is there a way around for this kind of requirement. Also is this possible if the system is a member of Active Directory.

Thank you.

Comment: It is a non trivial question. I recommend to start reading here. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_ENABLING_AND_USING_THIRD_PARTY_FEATURE_INSTALL_AND_UPDATE_1925_OVER.html

Answer (score 0):

Notes 8 provides a framework for automatically deploying "widgets" to end users; and one type of widget is an eclipse plug-in. You can set up a Widget Catalog database and you can use Notes policies to force particular end users to be in a Widget category - the category defines which widgets, including plug-ins, will be pushed and installed for a user.  So you would essentially need to do the following:

- Create a Notes Update Site database
- Create a Notes Widget Catalog database
- Import your plug-in jar's to the Update Site
- Create a wrapper widget document which points to your update site and particular plug-in
- Place the widget document in a widget category in the widget catalog
- Define a Notes Desktop policy which specified the widget category
- Add users to the new policy

Note - when users receive a widget which is an eclipse plug-in, they will be notified and will be required to re-start the Notes client.

For details on each of the steps, check out the IBM site linked to by Simon.